# Can some one tell me the asymptotic behavior of following series for large n?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

$$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \left(\frac{1}{\left(2k-1+2^{1/\alpha}\right)^\alpha} - \frac{1}{\left(2k+2^{1/\alpha}\right)^\alpha}\right),$$ where $0<\alpha<2$.

Comment: Can you do $\alpha=1?$  What have you tried?

Comment: $\alpha \neq 1$

Comment: But it could be $1$.  When I am asked to prove a general statement, one way I approach it is to look for specific cases I can handle.  Often proving the specific case gives insight for proving the general case.  Here $\alpha=1$ makes it easier to combine the two fractions and makes the denominators simpler.  It is a good place to start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I suggested, let us start with the case $\alpha=1$ because it is simplest.  In that case
$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \left(\frac{1}{\left(2k-1+2^{1/\alpha}\right)^\alpha} - \frac{1}{\left(2k+2^{1/\alpha}\right)^\alpha}\right)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \left(\frac{1}{2k+1} - \frac{1}{2k+2}\right)\\
=\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \left(\frac{1}{(2k+1)(2k+2)} \right)\\=\frac 12 \left(H_{n+\frac 12}-H_{n+1}-1+\log(4)\right)$$
where $H_n$ is the $n$th harmonic number and the calculation is from [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%201%2F(2k%2B1)%2F(2k%2B2)%20from%201%20to%20n).
  As $H_{n+\frac 12}-H_{n+1} \approx \log(n+1)-\log(n+\frac 12)\approx \frac 1{2n}$ the sum is about $\log(2)-\frac 12-\frac 1{4n}$
For the general case
$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \left(\frac{1}{\left(2k-1+2^{1/\alpha}\right)^\alpha} - \frac{1}{\left(2k+2^{1/\alpha}\right)^\alpha}\right)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \left(\frac{\left(2k+2^{1/\alpha}\right)^\alpha-\left(2k-1+2^{1/\alpha}\right)^\alpha}{\left(2k-1+2^{1/\alpha}\right)^\alpha\left(2k+2^{1/\alpha}\right)^\alpha}\right)$$
If we are interested in how the sum grows asymptotically with $n$ we can assume the lower limit is rather large instead of $1$. Then the $2^{1/\alpha}$s will not matter and the numerator becomes $(2k)^\alpha(1-(1-\frac 1{(2k)})^\alpha)\approx \alpha(2k)^{\alpha-1}$.  With an upper limit of $\infty$ the sum will converge for all $\alpha \gt 0$.  To find the dependence at $\infty$ we will study the sum from $n$ to infinity instead of $1$ to $n$ by converting to an integral.
$$\sum\limits_{k=n}^\infty \left(\frac{\left(2k+2^{1/\alpha}\right)^\alpha-\left(2k-1+2^{1/\alpha}\right)^\alpha}{\left(2k-1+2^{1/\alpha}\right)^\alpha\left(2k+2^{1/\alpha}\right)^\alpha}\right)\approx \sum_n^\infty \frac {\alpha (2k)^{\alpha-1}}{(2k)^{2\alpha}}\\
=\sum_n^\infty \alpha (2k)^{-1-\alpha}\approx \int_n^\infty\alpha(2x)^{-1-\alpha}dx\\=\frac {n^{-\alpha}}{2^{1+\alpha}\alpha}$$ so the sum decreases from the limit at $\infty$ (whatever it is) like this.

Comment: I have done the formal derivation for the case $\alpha=1$, that gives me $\frac{1}{2}\left( 2 log(2) -1 -\frac{1}{2n} \right)$, are you agree with this?
It is much closer to the expression concluded by you but you missed on the factor $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Yes, I missed the factor copying over from Alpha.  Fixed

Comment: Many thanks @ross.
I'm still struggling for the rest of case $\alpha \neq 1$. Can you help me in finding the constant for the case $\alpha>0$.

Comment: dear many thanks. so we can say that
$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{ (2k+2^{1/\alpha} )^\alpha - (2k-1+2^{1/\alpha})^\alpha  } {(2k-1+2^{1/\alpha})^\alpha (2k+2^{1/\alpha} )^\alpha} \right)  = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} \left(\frac{ (2k+2^{1/\alpha} )^\alpha - (2k-1+2^{1/\alpha})^\alpha  } {(2k-1+2^{1/\alpha})^\alpha (2k+2^{1/\alpha} )^\alpha} \right) + \sum\limits_{k=n}^{\infty} \left(\frac{ (2k+2^{1/\alpha} )^\alpha - (2k-1+2^{1/\alpha})^\alpha  } {(2k-1+2^{1/\alpha})^\alpha (2k+2^{1/\alpha} )^\alpha} \right) $
(P.S. see also the next comment)

Comment: $\sum\limits_{k=n}^{\infty} \left(\frac{ (2k+2^{1/\alpha} )^\alpha - (2k-1+2^{1/\alpha})^\alpha  } {(2k-1+2^{1/\alpha})^\alpha (2k+2^{1/\alpha} )^\alpha} \right)  = \frac{n^{-\alpha}}{2^{1+\alpha}\alpha}$
thus in a sense,we can say
$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{ (2k+2^{1/\alpha} )^\alpha - (2k-1+2^{1/\alpha})^\alpha  } {(2k-1+2^{1/\alpha})^\alpha (2k+2^{1/\alpha})^\alpha} \right)  \approx 
\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} \left(\frac{ (2k+2^{1/\alpha} )^\alpha - (2k-1+2^{1/\alpha})^\alpha } {(2k-1+2^{1/\alpha})^\alpha (2k+2^{1/\alpha})^\alpha} \right) +\frac{n^{-\alpha}}{2^{1+\alpha}\alpha}$

Comment: I still have little ambiguity, how to deal with  
$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} \left(\frac{ (2k+2^{1/\alpha} )^\alpha - (2k-1+2^{1/\alpha})^\alpha  } {(2k-1+2^{1/\alpha})^\alpha (2k+2^{1/\alpha})^\alpha} \right)$  ?

I tried with the binomial expansion of  $(2k-1+2^{1/\alpha})^\alpha$, but is not working as I want.
Could you be so kind to help me to solve this ?

Comment: I ignored the $2^{1/\alpha}$ as promised.  Then $(2k-1)^\alpha=(2k)^\alpha(1-\frac 1{2k})^\alpha \approx (2k)^\alpha(1-\frac{\alpha}{2k}$ using $(1+x)^n \approx 1+nx$ for $x \ll 1$

Comment: Yes, thanks.
for $\alpha=1$, I compared the results with numerical simulations, they are perfectly agreed.
For the rest case $\alpha>0$, shall we conclude the fact that, the sum from 1 to $n$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$, we have $\frac{n^{-\alpha}}{ 2^{1+\alpha}\alpha}$?

Comment: The sum will be about  $L(\alpha)-\frac{n^{-\alpha}}{2^{1+\alpha}\alpha}$ where $L(\alpha)$ is the sum all the way to infinity.  I don't know a good way to compute it, but haven't tried just plugging into Alpha.  It might be able to sum the series like it could the $\alpha=1$ case.

Comment: Many thanks. Plugging $\alpha$, you mean put (lets say $\alpha=0.5$ or $1.5$)? and observe the constants.
for the asymptotic I totally agreed that it should grow $n^{-\alpha}$, but I want to go a little step further in order to calculate constants.

Comment: No, plugging into Wolfram Alpha to get the sum to infinity.  That is how I got the sum in the $\alpha=1$ case.

Comment: $$\sum\limits_{k=1}^n(\frac{1}{(2 k - 1 + 2^{1/\alpha})^\alpha} -\frac{1}{(2k+ 2^{1/\alpha})^\alpha}) = 2^{-\alpha}(\zeta(\alpha,\frac{1}{2}(1+2^{1/\alpha})+n)+\zeta(\alpha, \frac{1}{2} (2 + 2^{\frac{1}{\alpha}}) + n)+\zeta(\alpha, \frac{1}{2} (1 + 2^{1/\alpha})) - \zeta(\alpha, \frac{1}{2} (2 + 2^{1/\alpha})))$$

while evaluating the sum from $1\rightarrow n$, I got the partial sum which is written in expression. we already have the results from $n\rightarrow\infty$ . Can you tell me how to deal with $\zeta$ function?

Comment: I am not familiar with it.  I would follow the link in the other answer and try to find an expression that can give you an expansion at infinity.  I took a glance a while back and nothing jumped out at me.  Each of the two sums will diverge for $\alpha \le 1$.  The advantage of my approach is that the divergence is canceled analytically.

Comment: I posted in a question.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over \pars{2k + s}^{\alpha}} & =
2^{-a}\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over \pars{k + s/2}^{\alpha}} =
2^{-a}\zeta\pars{a,{s + 2 \over 2}}\,,\quad\Re\pars{\alpha} > 1\,,\quad
s \not= 0,-2,-4,\ldots
\end{align}

> where $\ds{\zeta}$ is the [Hurwitz Zeta Function](http://dlmf.nist.gov/25.11.E1). Now, you can finish your exercise.

If you're still interested in the asymptotic behaviour, you can see
[this identity](http://dlmf.nist.gov/25.11.E5).

Comment: Many thanks. 
Can we avoid Hurwitz Zeta Function?
If no, then zeta function helps us in finding large $n$ asymptotic?

Comment: How we can compute Hurwitz Zeta Function?

Comment: Besides particular values, it's evaluated by some CAS or/and by numerical means.